# Ionic components not visible in iOS 11

Tags: cordova, ionic3, ios11

I have an issue with the latest Ionic with iOS 11. Ionic header label and buttons are not appearing after editing some form values like text area. [image]

Is it something related to `z-index` or any other CSS property. The good thing is if I do any CSS changes by inspecting elements, the buttons and label are started appearing.

Comment: The problem components are ionic-header, ioni-toolbar and ionic-butttons.

Answer (score 0):

You should add "viewport-fit=cover" to your  meta viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 ,minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
```